# Stop contact form from replying in new tab. My OCD is fistfighting my ADD over contact form

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, email

this is my html, my php, and ajax for a contact form. It works great except it post the relpys in a new browser tab. I have spent hours trying to correct it. Please help.

html-

```
 <!-- form fields -->
    <form action="assets/php/contact.php" method="post" name="contactform" id="contactform" class=" animated out" data-animation="fadeInUp" data-delay="0">

      <fieldset>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input class="form-control" type="text" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject">
            </div>
          </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <textarea class="form-control" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Message..."></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>

      <!-- submit button -->
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send message" id="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
      </div>

      <div id="alert"></div>

    </form>
```

PHP-

```
if(!$_POST) exit;

// Email address verification, do not edit.
function isEmail($email) {
    return(preg_match("/^[-_.[:alnum:]]+@((([[:alnum:]]|[[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]-]*[[:alnum:]])\.)+(ad|ae|aero|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|arpa|as|at|au|aw|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|biz|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|com|coop|cr|cs|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|edu|ee|eg|eh|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gov|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|in|info|int|io|iq|ir|is|it|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|me|mg|mh|mil|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|museum|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|name|nc|ne|net|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nt|nu|nz|om|org|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|pro|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|st|su|sv|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|um|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw)$|(([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5])\.){3}([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5]))$/i",$email));
}

if (!defined("PHP_EOL")) define("PHP_EOL", "\r\n");

    $name     = $_POST['name'];
    $email    = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    if(trim($name) == '') {
        echo '<div class="notification error clearfix"><p><strong>Attention!</strong> You must enter your name.</p></div>';
        exit();
    } else if(trim($email) == '') {
        echo '<div class="notification error clearfix"><p><strong>Attention!</strong> Please enter a valid email address.</p></div>';
        exit();
    } else if(!isEmail($email)) {
        echo '<div class="notification error clearfix"><p><strong>Attention!</strong> You have entered an invalid e-mail address, try again.</p></div>';
        exit();
    }

    if(trim($message) == '') {
        echo '<div class="notification error clearfix"><p><strong>Attention!</strong> Please enter your message.</p></div>';
        exit();
    } 

    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $message = stripslashes($message);
    }


    // Configuration option.
    // Enter the email address that you want to emails to be sent to.
    // Example $address = "joe.doe@yourdomain.com";

    $address = "your@email.com";


    // Configuration option.
    // i.e. The standard subject will appear as, "You've been contacted by John Doe."

    // Example, $e_subject = '$name . ' has contacted you via Your Website.';

    $e_subject = 'You\'ve been contacted by ' . $name . '.';


    // Configuration option.
    // You can change this if you feel that you need to.
    // Developers, you may wish to add more fields to the form, in which case you must be sure to add them here.

    $e_body = "You have been contacted by $name ." . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
    $e_content = "\"$message\"" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
    $e_reply = "You can contact $name via email, $email";

    $msg = wordwrap( $e_body . $e_content . $e_reply, 70 );

    $headers = "From: $email" . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $email" . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable" . PHP_EOL;

    if(mail($address, $e_subject, $msg, $headers)) {

        // Email has sent successfully, echo a success page.

        echo "<fieldset>";
        echo "<div id='success_page'>";
        echo "<div class='notification success clearfix'><p>Thank you <strong>$name</strong>, your message has been submitted to us.</p></div>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "</fieldset>";

    } else {

        echo 'ERROR!';

    }
```

JS-

```
/* ==============================================
    Contact Form
=============================================== */

$('#contactform').submit(function(){

    var action = $(this).attr('action');

    $("#alert").slideUp(750,function() {
        $('#alert').hide();

    $('#submit')
        .after('<img src="assets/images/ajax-loader.GIF" class="contactloader" />')
        .attr('disabled','disabled');

    $.post(action, {
        name: $('#name').val(),
        email: $('#email').val(),
        message: $('#message').val()
    },
        function(data){
            document.getElementById('alert').innerHTML = data;
            $('#alert').slideDown('slow');
            $('#contactform img.contactloader').fadeOut('slow',function(){$(this).remove();});
            $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
            if(data.match('success') !== null) {
                $('#name').val('');
                $('#email').val('');
                $('#message').val('');
            }
        }
    );

    });

    return false;

});
```

I want error or success messages to show on the contact.html page and not open a new browser tab.
Thank you advance for help restore my sanity.
Cheers

Comment: Nothing in this code would open a new tab.  You must have some other code that is applying that behavior.  However, you probably should be preventing the default of the submit, otherwise the form will still perform the native submit, and navigate to contact.php  See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Comment: I know, right! I see nothing also and it´s maddening. I will try your answer. For just a quick work around, I included an iframe on the html page and forced it to post. Thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to prevent the default form submit from firing, which will post the content to the URL in your form action.

```
$('#contactform').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    ...
});
```

Comment: No joy. Still defaulting to contact.php page. Maddening!

Comment: Is your contact form JavaScript being called at all? If not, you may need to wrap it in an onload check, such as `$(function () { ... });`, to ensure that `#contactform` exists in the DOM before adding events to it.